# Rename the "Dropbox (Personal)" folder?

Tags: dropbox

I use Dropbox for business on my machine, and so I have a `Dropbox (Personal)` folder, a `Dropbox (mybusiness)` folder, and a symlink from `Dropbox` to `Dropbox (Personal)`.

The `Dropbox (Personal)` folder is causing me problems, because I have code in a subdirectory, and when I try to use a virtualenv with pip, it objects to the spaces in the path.

I've renamed `Dropbox (Personal)` to `Dropbox_Personal` and updated the symlink, but now the Dropbox app says it won't work until I change the name back.

Is there a way I can tell it just to use the new folder?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Try this (which is working for me *so far*) on MacOS:

- Make a backup
- Make another backup, somewhere else.
- Create a "Dropbox" folder in whatever location you want.
- Copy your files from "Dropbox (Personal)" to the new "Dropbox"
- Remove/delete the "Dropbox (Personal)" folder.
- At this point the Dropbox app will complain and offer to 'Relink' or 'Quit'.
- 'Quit'
- Create a symbolic link called "Dropbox (Personal)" pointing to your recently created "Dropbox" folder.

  ```
    ln -s /pathtofolder/Dropbox "Dropbox (Personal)"
  ```
- Restart the Dropbox App.

At this point, for me, it works well.

This is slightly different (I think) to other suggestions because in this case the "Dropbox" folder is a 'real' folder. The Dropbox app is happy because it syncs with "Dropbox (Personal)" and my programs are working directly on "Dropbox" so there are no issues with embedded spaces.

Comment: Seems rather hacky at best.

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 20.04. Hacky but a great way to get rid of paths with special characters.

Comment: Quicker: 1. Quit the app 2. Rename folder 3. Simlink 4. Start the app.

Comment: Explaining the above comment a bit more, in retrospect: you don't need to copy and delete the original folder (and make 2 backups!) when you can simply and safely rename it to "Dropbox". Then use the `ln -s ...` command shown above to create the symlink (step 3 in the comment).

Answer (score 0):

You can rename "Dropbox (Personal)" back to Dropbox and symlink "Dropbox (Personal)" to it, you did remove the symlink (~/Dropbox) first and recreate later.

> cd ~
>
> rm -f Dropbox && mv "Dropbox (Personal)" Dropbox && ln -s Dropbox "Dropbox (Personal)"

You can make symbolic links invisible in the Finder

> chflags -h hidden ~/"Dropbox (Personal)"